# Who's the antecedent of His in "through..His creative inspiration?"

Tags: john

1In the beginning the Living Expression was already there. And the Living Expression was with God, yet fully God. 2They were together—face-to-face, in the very beginning. 3And through his creative inspiration this Living Expression made all things, for nothing has existence apart from him! John 1:1-3 TPT

Through whose creative inspiration did Jesus, the living expression make all things? God's? or His own?

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Up-voted +1. Please see the Tour and the Help ( below, left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TPT version, quoited by the OP, is so free that it is really an interpretive paraphrase which takes some literary liberties with the Greek text.  So here is my overly literal translation directly from the Greek of John 1:1-3

> In [the] beginning was the Logos, and the Logos was with God and the
> Logos was God.  He was in [the] beginning with God.  All things
> through Him came into being and without Him came into being not one
> [thing] that has come into being.

The antecedent of all the pronouns here is Logos, which is translated by most versions as, "the word".  This continues through verse 4 as well.

Comment: So Jesus made all things through His own inspiration? How does that make sense? Clear that to me and I'll give you a green tick. ^^ along with an upvote.

Comment: @KokoGurung - the word "inspiration" is not in the Greek text.  However, from this text and others like John 1:10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2, we indeed find that Jesus was the creator of all things.

Comment: Yes btw tpt was written from both greek and Aramaic nt texts. TPTs rendering of John 1:3 sounds like Jesus made all things through God's inspiration. He saw what God did. So he did the same. (John 5:19). The father creates, so the son also creates.

Comment: @KokoGurung - perhaps, but the Aramaic does not have the word "inspiration" either.

Comment: Well I still love TPT T^T. It's easy to understand for a non native speaker like me.

Comment: @KokoGurung - OK, but be careful with a version that places words and phrase in the text that do not exist in the original like, "face to face", "living", "expression", "creative", "inspiration", etc.